# PDO: could not find driver

Tags: php, pdo, symfony

I don't understand because I have the PDO_MYSQL extention.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItNDN.png)

[phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESIme.png)

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: show us the configuration of your doctrine in your symfony configuration file. Which driver did you put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your root Symfony3 directory enter:

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

Then see if you are missing any installation requirements.

Comment: Understood ! I use my Bash Ubuntu for Windows so it not use my WAMP! That's why I don't have PDO installed! I will correct that, thx!